# ReST in .NET Core Framework 2.1 Returning a Single Record

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core

I'm obviously missing something here, but cannot seem to make this work.

This code works to return all the (fake) posts from the given URL

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Post>));

var streamTask = client.GetStreamAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");

var postList = serializer.ReadObject(await streamTask) as List<Post>;

return View(postList);
```

However, if I try and return a single post ("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2") it says that my postList object is empty.

If I call it asynchronously using GetStringAsync instead of Stream then I get the record back.

```
var stringTask = client.GetStringAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2");
var msg = await stringTask;
```

works, but does not automatically create a list of Post objects.

Can someone please explain what is going on when I request a single record and if there is an easier fix than using two separate calls?

Comment: Without seeing your webservice, my spider sense is telling me that the return type of the second URL returns a SINGLE post without a collection wrapper around it. You need a `new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Post))` and then cast it to `Post` rather than `List<Post>`.

Comment: Try the `client.GetStringAsync` with the same URL as the `client.GetStreamAsync`

Comment: What error, exception, or output are you getting? Also @Aron is probably right!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot show you the web service code as I am using a free one from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com. I am not getting any error, just getting 0 records in my list. You are correct @Aron, it is only a single JSON record that comes back and not a list.